# Node - Bird API

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to npm and node. I have cloned this [repository](https://github.com/jzarca01/node-bird) and am trying to run the given example.

I've installed all dependencies with `sudo npm install` and `sudo npm install -g nodemon`

In `index.js` I've input my email in `await bird.login('enter-your-email@here.com')`. I then run `sudo node index.js` and am then `prompt: verifyCode:`. I then past my verification code which i have received from my email, but once I hit enter nothing happens it just exits.

What I am expecting to have returned is a list of lat/lon of all birds in the set lat/lon and radius.
Does anyone know if I am running this correctly or need any additional components?

Comment: But what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Bigga_HD, again, I am very new, but to my understanding from the repo instructions return a list of lat/lon of all Birds in the set lat/lon and radius?

Comment: Go to `config\config.js` file copy the **`stripeToken`** use that to verify your email, after that, you should receive an email to verify that it's really you, and what happens after, well see it for your self.

Comment: @Bigga_HD when you say use the `stripeToken` to verify my email what exactly do you mean by that? Because I'm already receiving emails to verify its really me, and in the email is a token which i copy and then paste into the command line to `verifyCode:`. but then nothing happens once i paste the token in, it just returns nothing..